# Filtering while summarizing in python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, pandas-groupby

I am an R user currently learning python.

Usually, I use dplyr to group by and summarize my data. For e.g.,

```
data1 %>%
   dplyr::group_by(city) %>%
   dplyr::summarize(unique_customers = n_distinct(user_id, na.rm = TRUE),
                 converted_customers = n_distinct(user_id[type == "CONVERTED"], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   data.frame()
```

I have been able to achieve the group_by and the unique_customers, but I am having some trouble putting the condition type == "CONVERTED" in python. How do I do this?

Edit:
My python code as it stands now:

```
data1.fillna(method = "ffill").groupby("city").agg({"user_id": "nunique"})
```

Comment: apply(lambda x: (x=='CONVERTED'))  ::: Similar to what you want to achieve in R

Comment: I am getting the unique count of customers for each city with this code: data1.fillna(method = "ffill").groupby("city").agg({"user_id": "nunique"}) but I would like to apply a filter from another column "type", which should be filtered to only CONVERTED, similar to case when statements in sql. This is where I am stuck. @roganjosh

Comment: I am ok with either pandas or pure python.

Comment: I found only the "pandas-groupby" tag. Hope this works.

Comment: I already added the pandas tag for you

Comment: @roganjosh Hey why does my question have a -1 vote?

Comment: It isn't mine so I can only speculate, but the fact that you hadn't shown any of your python (which turned out to be pandas) approach at the start, it came across as a "please translate this code for me". If you haven't already done so, please have a look through how to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that voting is based on a person's perception of how useful a question is likely to be for future programmers with the same issue, not anything to do with the individual asking

Comment: Got it...........

Answer (score 0):

```
data1[data1.type=='CONVERTED'].fillna(method = "ffill").groupby("city").agg({"user_id": "nunique"})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer @Mysterious I think this will only give the converted_customers, right? I need both the unique_customers and converted_customers.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to translate your R code into python using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
from datar.all import f, group_by, summarize, n_distinct

data1 >> \
   group_by(f.city) >> \
   summarize(
      unique_customers=n_distinct(f.user_id, na_rm=True),
      converted_customers=n_distinct(f.user_id[f.type == "CONVERTED"], na_rm=True)
   )
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.